# ISO-8859-7 Decoding Issue

Tags: php, email, imap, iso-8859-1, gmail-imap

> Issue: Non-Latin characters wont display properly. Example: [here](https://i.gyazo.com/d7d2bd17236734ec2b0c85e67e7a21d1.png).

I worked out the issue is my page does not support ISO-8859-7 characters which is Latin/Greek context.

> What Im trying to achieve:

Basically I need to get the greek characters to display properly. Ξ Λ are examples. It also seems like Twitter, Gmail, Google and StackOverflow support these characters. How come when I use gmails IMAP to show the subject and From section it shows it like this:

```
"=?ISO-8859-7?Q?=CE_=CB_R_O_N_-_New_MV!!_(via_Twitter)?="
```

When it should be showing exactly like:

```
Ξ Λ R O N - New MV!! (via Twitter)
```

Is there anyway to be full sure all characters will display properly?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I have, Read the very top.

Answer (score 0):

### The following finally fixed the issue:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
[...]
$inbox_from[] = str_replace('"',"", str_replace("_"," ", mb_decode_mimeheader($inbox_overview[0]->from)));
```

The str_replace just removes the unnecessary start/end "..." and also replaces the _ with spaces.